# why this error bar analysis did not work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

here, i am trying to make an errorbar by using tidyverse and ggplot2. but i failed again and again. I am very new in R and learning basics of R.
i would request you to help me please.

```
df<- data.frame("type"= c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f","f"),
                "shh"= c(12,11,10,16,14,12,15, 16, 17,13))
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df_summary<- df %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(Mean_t= mean(shh),
            Sd_t= sd(shh),
            n_t= n(),
            se_t= sd(shh)/ sqrt(n()))
df_plot<- ggplot(df_summary, aes(type, Mean_t))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= Mean_t-Sd_t, ymax= Mean_t+Sd_t), width=0.2)
df_plot
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me: Error bars are plotted for both bars. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: df_plot does not work in my computer,does it?

Comment: `df_plot` is just an object of class `ggplot` which stores your plot. It should be executed (i.e. the plot should show up in the plot window) automatically if you simply call it, which you seem to do in the last line. Have you tried not saving the `ggplot(...)` call to an object (`df_plot`) and just call it directly?

Comment: thank you. i did it.